# Scrapy replace() or strip() br/ tags from data

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to make my scraped text data look cleaner and remove the `<br>` tag or replace it with an actual linebreak in the csv:

```html
<div>
  "This is an example."
   <br>
   "This is an example too."
<div>
```

when i am scraping the text with xpath and use the strip() function `response.xpath('//div//text()').extract().strip()`  (i use an itemloader, so the real function looks a bit different, but its basically the same) the Output looks like this:

```html
['This is an example text.',
'',
'This is an example too.'],

#data in csv file:
"This is an example text.,This is an example too."
```

Now I either would like to remove the `<br>` tag, or the comma as its whole, so the Outcome looks like this: `"This is an example text. This is an example too"`

or i would like to replace it with an actual line break:

```html
"This is an example text. 
This is an example too."
```

I already tried several .strip() commands i.e. `.strip(u'\u0027')` to remove the quotes or `.strip(u'\00A0')` to remove the blanks but nothing worked

Can i actually do this with scrapy? If yes any ideas how? If not do I have to do this later with pandas?

Comment: I see that you already got your answer, but this also can be done with response.xpath('string(//div)').get(), try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
response.xpath(''.join('//div//text()')).extract()
```

Comment: thanks man this worked (beacause I used ItemLoader I had to use "output_processor=Join(' ')"

Answer (score 0):

Use the replace function to replace commas at the end of lines

```
result = response.xpath('//div//text()').extract().strip().replace(",\n", "\n")
```

Comment: this only removes the commas in the text  "this is ,an example" --> "this is an example"

Comment: @JarodSantoso, no, it replaces commas followed by a newline with with a newlline